# C# XML Read All Child Nodes Of A Specific Node

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

So I have a program that reads all the name nodes in a XML file and adds these to a Combo Box. On a button click, it then takes this response and needs to get all the other data from the child nodes of the node the name is in.

The XML document:

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Greg</Name>
        <Age>23</Age>
        <Height>200</Height>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Age>34</Age>
        <Height>230</Height>
    </Person>
</People>
```

What I've got so far:

```
            XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
            Doc.Load(FilePath);
            foreach (XmlNode Node in Doc.SelectNodes("People/Person"))
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(Node.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText);
            }
            string RegPicked = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            foreach (XmlNode xNode in Doc.SelectNodes("People/Person"))
                if (xNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText == RegPicked)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = xNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.ToString();
                }
             Doc.Save(FilePath);
```

When I run the code I just get "System.Xml.XmlChildNodes" in the text box.
I know I've done something wrong but I'm not sure what.

Comment: They are XmlChildnodes (the ToString() method uses the basic .net ToString(), in which case you get the type's FullName). You would have to evaluate the ChildNodes, like this page describes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: What exactly do you want in the TextBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to distinguished child node:

```
textBox1.Text = xNode.ParentNode.ChildNodes.SelectSingleNode("age").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this, you will get all the elements inside the parent of the node you are searching the value of.

```
 string str = @"<People>
                        <Person>
                            <Name>Greg</Name>
                            <Age>23</Age>
                            <Height>200</Height>
                        </Person>
                        <Person>
                            <Name>John</Name>
                            <Age>34</Age>
                            <Height>230</Height>
                        </Person>
                    </People>";

        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
        var xmlURL = (from el in xdoc.Descendants("Name")
                     where el.Value == "John"
                     select el.Parent).First().ToString();
```